# How to ssh another VM without password

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

Now, I have two SuSe11SP3 VM. I want to ssh another VM without password. Because I often use `scp` to copy files between the two VMs. But the password is too long, I don't want to change password. I know maybe I can use publickey, my question is how can I achieve by using script.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it by writing script, ansible playbook, etc.

Comment: you can generate ssh keys and share them between machines, then your script could run scp between them without the need for a pw. Note: this method is insecure as an empty pw for an ssh key is usually a bad idea. but if you own both vm's an they are both running on your desktop it should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As General said, you could use `ssh-keygen` to create a pair of keys without password and copy `.pub` key to another VM's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`